# using document() function in .NET XSLT generates error

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'd like to use embedded resources in my XSLT file, but while invoking 'document(...)' C# complains that "Error during loading document ..."

I'd like to use defined resources in XSLT file and get them by this: "document('')/*/my:resources/*"...

How can i do that??

ex xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="xslt-gruper-v1.2.xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="my">

     <my:resources>
      <one>tryb</one>
     </my:resources>

     <xsl:variable name="res" select="document('')/*/my:resources/("/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can i get access to such structure without exceptions in C#? I'll add that during static transform via ex. Opera everything works fine.

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="res" select="document('')/*/my:resources/("/>
> ```

**The value of the `select` attribute is not a syntactically correct XPath expression**. Every compliant XSLT processor must raise an error.

**Solution**:

Correct the above to:

```
<xsl:variable name="vRes" select="document('')/*/my:resources"/>
```

If there is still an exception raised, do read about the [XsltSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings(v=VS.100).aspx) class.

**Then create an instance of XsltSettings** with [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163499(v=VS.100).aspx), like this:

```
XsltSettings(true, false)
```

**Do not enable scripting** -- keep the second argument of the constructor as `false`.

**Below is a more complete code snippet**:

```
// Create the XsltSettings object with document() enabled and script disabled.
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true,false);

// Create the XslCompiledTransform object and load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("sort.xsl", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

**Update**: Another possible reason for an error is when the XSLT stylesheet is dynamically created in memory (doesn't come from file). In this case an XSLT processor typically cannot resolve the relative uri in `document('')`.

In this last case the solution is to make the wanted element the content of an `xsl:variable` and to use the `xxx:node-set()` extension function to address this element.

Comment: +1 Very good answer. Some times, when `document('')` gives me problems, I use p/2 function (knowing that input an stylesheet come from the same directory)

Comment: @Simon: the +1 was forgotten it seems ;). I'll add one, it's a good answer.

Comment: I am having the same problem but I don't see the answer to the question. What is p/2 function? How do you use Node-set() as a variable lookup?

Comment: @goroth node-set() selects the temporary tree that is the value of the variable -- more precisely, converts the RTF (Result-Tree-Fragment) that is the value of the variable to an ordinary XPath document node, which you can operate on.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thanks for the information. I had a similar problem but someone was able to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365166/document-function-errors-when-calling-the-net-transform-method

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair out for an entire day and a half, I finally figured out the solution to an identical issue I was seeing.

My code:

NUnit Test:

```
[Test]
public void Transform_WhenXslUsesTheDocumentFunction_DoesNotThrow()
{
    //Arrange
    string testOutputPath = GetTestOutputPath(
        nameof(Transform_WhenXslUsesTheDocumentFunction_DoesNotThrow)
        );
    string inputXsl = TestFilePaths.GetResource("Import\\DocumentImporter.xsl");
    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
    XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
    XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslCompiledTransform.Load(inputXsl, xsltSettings, resolver);

    //Act
    TestDelegate testDelegate = () => xslCompiledTransform.Transform(
        TestFilePaths.MinimumValidXml
        , testOutputPath
        );

    //Assert
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(testDelegate);
}
```

DocumentImporter.xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:variable name="DocumentPath" select="'./Document.xml'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="DocumentXML" select="document($DocumentPath)"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$DocumentXML//Message"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Document.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Message>Document Message</Message>
```

Eventually I found this:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26969

Informing me that I needed to use a new .Net Core "Feature" which would allow me to use my external xml document, using the snippet:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);
```

Final code that works:

```
[Test]
public void Transform_WhenXslUsesTheDocumentFunction_DoesNotThrow()
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);

    //Arrange
    string testOutputPath = GetTestOutputPath(
        nameof(Transform_WhenXslUsesTheDocumentFunction_DoesNotThrow)
        );
    string inputXsl = TestFilePaths.GetResource("Import\\DocumentImporter.xsl");
    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
    XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
    XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslCompiledTransform.Load(inputXsl, xsltSettings, resolver);

    //Act
    TestDelegate testDelegate = () => xslCompiledTransform.Transform(
        TestFilePaths.MinimumValidXml
        , testOutputPath
        );

    //Assert
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(testDelegate);
}
```