# Document('') function errors when calling the .NET Transform method

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xslt file that contains a xsl variable that I am using like a lookup table.

```
<xsl:variable name="TestLookup">
    <lookup code="A" means="Test A"/>
    <lookup code="B" means="Test B"/>
    <lookup code="C" means="Test C"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I call it like this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='TestLookup']/lookup[@code=current()]/@means"/>
```

When I call the Transform method in .NET I get the following errors:

```
An error occurred while loading document ''
This operation is not supported for a relative URI.
```

Basically it is telling me that it can't find the document.
I need some way of creating a lookup table in the xslt file and be able to call it with the Transform command in .NET.

This article had the same problem but I didn't see an answer. Something about p/2 function?
It also listed the node-set() but I can't find any good article on using node-set as a lookup table.
[using document() function in .NET XSLT generates error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710369/using-document-function-in-net-xslt-generates-error)


**Adding More Code** 

 

.NET CODE

```
' get the xml from SQL    
Dim xmlData As String = sqlXmlReader.Item("XmlData").ToString()

' read the xslt file
Using styleSheet = New StreamReader("XSLTTestFile.xslt")
    ' load the stylesheet from a resource
    Using styleSheetReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(styleSheet)
        Dim xslt = New XslCompiledTransform()
        Dim xsltSettings = New XsltSettings(True, False)            
        xsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = True

        ' load the stylesheet for transformation
        xslt.Load(styleSheetReader, xsltSettings, New XmlUrlResolver())
        Using stringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter
            ' transform the xml document along with the stylesheet
            Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData)
            xslt.Transform(xmlDoc, Nothing, stringWriter)
            ' dump the transformation to the browser control
            _htmlString.Append(stringWriter.ToString())
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: The answer was to use `XsltSettings`. Did you try that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using document() function in .NET XSLT generates error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710369/using-document-function-in-net-xslt-generates-error)

Comment: Yes I did try the New XsltSettings(True, False) that is how I get the error and this might be a duplicate (as noted in the bottom of my explanation) but they never really answered the original.

Comment: Please show the code you used. This will reduce the confusion about which code you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload of the `Load` method that takes a string with the file name or URL  of the stylesheet, use that and `XslCompiledTransform` knows how to resolve `document('')`. So use `xslt.Load("XSLTTestFile.xslt", xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver())`.

Comment: The only thing that I can find to use is the XmlUrlReslover but that requires ResolveUri which I don't have a uri to the xsl. The xsl is on the file system not on the web.

Comment: Pass that file name to the `Load` method instead of wrestling with an XmlReader over a StreamReader.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Used Load("fileName",New XsltSettings(True, True), New XmlUrlResolver())... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `document('../xml/fieldcodes.xml')` in my xslt.
The following code was working for net452:

```
Dim readerSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
readerSettings.XmlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver() ' required for net452 and later
Using sr = New StringReader(XMLstr), sourceReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, readerSettings)
    Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb)
        xmlvalidTransformer.Transform(sourceReader, New XsltArgumentList(), writer) 
        Using resReader = New StringReader(sb.ToString()), reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(resReader, readerSettings)
            myResultDoc.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

When switching to .net core, this code throws the following exception:

```
Exception: System.Exception: An error occurred while loading document '../xml/fieldcodes.xml'. See InnerException for a complete description of the error.
 ---> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: An error occurred while loading document '../xml/fieldcodes.xml'. See InnerException for a complete description of the error. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.
   at System.Xml.XmlNullResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
:
```

I could fix it by changing the `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` method to this overload:

```
xmlvalidTransformer.Transform(sourceReader, New XsltArgumentList(), writer, New XmlUrlResolver()) ' New XmlUrlResolver() is required for .net core
```

The following line did fixed it as well, but I did not like to turn on this in general:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true)
```